# Lagrange resolvent in field extensions

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Here is a question I encountered in school:

Show that $\mathbb{Q}\left(\zeta_{21}\right)$ has exactly three subfields of degree 6 over $\mathbb{Q}$. Show that one of them is $\mathbb{Q}\left(\zeta_7\right)$, one is real, and the other is a cyclic extension $K / \mathbb{Q}\left(\zeta_3\right)$. Use a suitable Lagrange resolvent to find $a \in \mathbb{Q}\left(\zeta_3\right)$ such that $K=\mathbb{Q}\left(\zeta_3, \sqrt[3]{a}\right)$.

For the first two parts, I know that $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{21})/\mathbb{Q}$ has Galois group $\mathbb{Z}_{21}^\times$, then I can identify order 2 subgroups for the required subfields, where $K = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta+\zeta^{13})$.

I am not so familiar with Lagrange resolvent and need help to see how it is applied here.
Thank you!

Comment: Anyway, what is the order three automorphism $\tau$ of $K$ that has $\zeta_3$ as the fixed point? You want a non-zero element of the form
$$z=x+\zeta_3\tau(x)+\zeta_3^2\tau^2(x)\in K,$$ where $x\in K$.
Then $\tau(z)=\zeta^{-1}z$ and consequently $a=z^3$ works.

Comment: I recall having done this exercise (for myself), but I viewed  $K$ as $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_3,2\cos2\pi/7)$. It may (or may not) be easier to use your generating element. I haven't checked, and need more coffee anyway :-)

Comment: Ah, I get it, thank you:) In conclusion, to get a cube root, we want to find an element translated by $\zeta_3$ by generator of the corresponding Galois group, which can be done by considering the form called a Lagrange resolvent.

Comment: That's the idea! If you can make it work for any choice of $x$, feel free to post the calculation as an answer. That way you get more feedback (and you can mark the question as solved).